# How can I copy a character in a "casted" string?

Tags: c, string, casting, char, malloc

I am new to C language and I'm not on the right track. I am currently focusing on my C programming exam, but I currently don't get along with memory allocation. As a newbie, I don't know if I could possibly fix this, as I have no clue about it. I intentionally set a limit to the name's size (just name and last name with one space in between) and the job's. Also, please give a look at the allocated memory size, I'm not totally sure if it's right or not. I will give you an example.

**EDIT** FIXED MAIN ISSUE:

casting isn't necessary. E.g. string[i]=character.

**INPUT:**

```
 1. NAME: Elton Rana
 2. JOB: Programmer
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Elton (Programmer) Rana
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
  char name[20], job[20];
  scanf("%[^\n]s",name);
  scanf("%s",job);

  char space=' ';
  char character1='(';
  char character2=')';
  char* fullname=(char*) malloc((4+strlen(name)+strlen(job)) * sizeof(char));
  int savepos;

  for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
    if((char)name[i]==space){ //position of the space between name and last name
      savepos=i;
      break;
    }
  }

  int k=0,h=0;
  for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    if(i==savepos){
      fullname[i]= space; //places a space
      i++;
      fullname[i]= character1; //places a (
    }else if(i==(h+strlen(job)+2)){
      fullname[i]= character2; //places a )
      i++;
      fullname[i]= space; //places a space
    }else if(i<(strlen(name)+strlen(job)+2) && i>savepos+1){
        fullname[i]= job[k];  //places the job's name between ()
        k++;
    }else{
      fullname[i]=name[h]; //places the name
      h++;
      if(name[h]=='\0'){
        fullname[i]='\0';
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("%s\n",fullname);
  free(fullname);
}
```

Comment: You will never make it to being a programmer unless and until you learn to ***check the return*** on every input and every allocation. Blindly proceeding forward not knowing whether you received valid input or have a valid block of memory to work with invites *Undefined Behavior*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any of those casts to char.

Further, you really can't cast the expression on the left side anyway for plain old value (non-pointer) types. That's a compiler error.

Instead of this:

```
(char) fullname[i]= space; //places a space
```

This will suffice:

```
fullname[i]= space; //places a space
```

Similarly:

```
 (char) fullname[i]= (char) name[h];
```

Can just be this:

```
fullname[i]= name[h];
```

Comment: Thank you very much perhaps I was burnt out, lol

Answer (score -1):

Dude!

In my point of view, I recommend you to refer to `sprintf()` with `strtok()`.

If you need more specific help, just leave me a comment :D

---

When you use `sprintf()` you can print something where you want.

For example `printf()` is `sprintf(stdout, "Hello world\n")`.

In this case, we call `stdout` as a stream.

(No worry, you are going to understand `stream` by your self, when time goes by)

So, you can easily fill your char array with `spirntf()`

`sprintf(fullname, "%s (%s)%s", lastName, job, firstName)`

It's like, "hey, `printf("%s (%s)%s\n", lastName, job, firstName)` to `fullname`"

How can we make the `name` into `lastName` and `firstName`?

We can use `strtok()` in this situation.

```
char *lastName = strtok(name, " ");
char *firstName = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

Finally, it's going to be like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char name[20];
    char job[20];

    scanf("%[^\n]s", name);
    scanf("%s", job);

    char allocatedBuffer[100];  

    char *lastName = strtok(name, " ");
    char *firstName = strtok(NULL, " ");

    sprintf(allocatedBuffer, "%s (%s)%s", lastName, job, firstName);    

    printf("%s\n", allocatedBuffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wow this is really good, at glance I gave another meaning to strtok. It's just like str.substr in C++, but it works with "tokens" aka string pieces. Is that right?

Comment: @Habras Thanks, dude.
Yes, you alright! As you mentioned above, " " is a token!